# Why is this particular string of numbers too far to the left?

Tags: bug, markdown

On a [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/i-am-trying-to-solve-a-problem), there is a string of numbers. However, they are going too far to the left, and I see no reason for them to do so. Why are they doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was interpreted as Markdown for an ordered list with one list item numbered 110101. I can replicate this below as such:

8675309. List?
8675310. Ha

Note that setting the start number like this isn't a typical Markdown feature.

If you really feel the need to format a post that way, this can be circumvented/prevented by<sup>1</sup>:

- Inserting a backslash (`\`) between the number and the period
- Adding something at the beginning of the line that will not be visibly displayed, e.g., `$ $` (empty MathJax) or `&shy;` ([soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen))

372021. Here are three
$ $9001. lines in which
­90909. I avoid lists

---

<sup>1</sup> Other imaginative ways of getting around it welcome in comments.

Comment: it is limited to numbers with 10 digits or less